# How to hide section titles from main table of contents in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm working on docs for a Python project using Sphinx. The main page has a table of contents, and by default, the `toctree` directive in Sphinx includes section headings below page titles. I find this to be too much, usability-wise. Intuitively, I would expect one link per page. Having sub-links for all the sections makes the documentation look way more complex and overwhelming than it actually is.

The `:titlesonly:` option fixes this, but that also removes the section headings from the sidebar when actually on the page. I don't want to lose those, because they serve as a useful "current page" table of contents.

Is there a way to exclude section headings from the table of contents on the front page while keeping them in the sidebar?

### Example without `:titlesonly:`

**index.rst:**

```
Example Documentation
=====================

Table of Contents
-----------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   installation
   api
   support
```

**installation.rst:**

```
Installation
============

From PyPI
---------

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

From Source
-----------

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
```

(and so on for the other .rst files)

**index.html:**

[image]

**installation.html:**

[image]

### Example with `:titlesonly:`

**index.rst:**

```
Example Documentation
=====================

Table of Contents
-----------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :titlesonly:

   installation
   api
   support
```

(other .rst files unchanged)

**index.html:**

[image]

**installation.html**

[image]

Comment: Does setting the maxdepth option on your toctree directive to 1 achieve the result you want?

Comment: You can customize the CSS of the theme to hide elements.

Comment: @morric I tried that too. The result was the same, unfortunately.

Comment: @StevePiercy If so, that would work well. Do you have a suggestion for how to go about it, though? I see that the level 2 list items in the front page TOC have class "toctree-l2", but so do the level 2 list items in the sidebar, so I'm not sure how to distinguish between them.

Comment: You can use the classes further up the DOM to separate the left-hand and body bullets.  bodywrapper for the main text and sphinxsidebarwrapper would work, though there are others you could use if you prefer.

Comment: @morric Ah, that sounds like it would do the job. Thanks.